# What is the meaning of undecidability in Rice Theorem?

Tags: terminology, computability, undecidability, semi-decidability, rice-theorem

Rice theorem says **every non-trivial property of languages of Turing machines is undecidable**. what is the meaning of undecidability here? is it semi-decidable?

As an example the following language is R.E but it contains a non-trivial property

$A = \{x | \phi_x$ is defined for at least one input$ \}$

this language equals to $Empty$ $Complement$ and it is clearly r.e.(m-complete in fact) while non-emptiness property is non-trivial.

Comment: It means the same as everywhere else (in computability theory).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Undecidable means not decidable. Undecidable problems may or may not be semi-decidable.

To see that an undecidable problem is not necessarily semi-decidable, observe that there are uncountably many problems but, since each decidable or semi-decidable problem corresponds to a Turing machine, there are only countably many decidable and semi-decidable problems.