# Type of undecidability in Rice Theorem

Tags: terminology, computability, semi-decidability

Rice theorem says every non-trivial property of languages of Turing machines is undecidable.  As [David Richerby](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/9550/david-richerby) said in [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/what-is-the-meaning-of-undecidability-in-rice-theorem) :

> Undecidable means not decidable. Undecidable problems may or may not be semi-decidable.

I would like to know how to find out Rice Theorem leads to semi-decidability or non-semi-decidability?

As an example Rice Theorem is applicable to this r.e. language

> $A = \{x | \phi_x$ is defined for at least one input$ \}$

and also this non-r.e. language as well:

$\psi_p = x^2$

There is no algorithm to determine $\psi_p$ has that property at all while for $A$ we can simply run the program forever an see whether it accepts one input or not. I would like to know using Rice Theorem is there any way to determine this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rice's Theorem just says it's undecidable. Some undecidable languages are semi-decidable; some (almost all, in fact) of them aren't.

Comment: How may I find if the language is semi-decidable or non semi decidable?

Comment: You have to use your brain and figure it out on a case-by-case basis. There's no recipe that always works -- that's exactly what it means for something to be undecidable.

Comment: How do you prove the non computability of $\psi_p = x^2$? what method we may use to conclude the non-computability ?

Comment: See our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable).